# Google Sheets Data Validation dropdown from single cell CSV

Tags: csv, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is there a way to create Data Validation drop-down list from a CSV string located in a single cell? I know how to create data validation drop down and manually input those items, but I want to be able to refer to a cell with the CSV string of all items to create the dropdown. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, this is not yet possible in Google Sheets. CSV values need to be each in a separate cell. also, formulae as range input are not supported either.