# How to use Split array of a single cell for data validation dropdown?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to create data validation dropdown from a single cell which has all `,` separated values and I am splitting them using `SPLIT(K4,",")`. But when I apply the formula drop-down just goes away. Here is how it looks:

[image]

And here is where I have applied validation:

[image]

It just happens and I can't see any drop-down here. Even validation doesn't work as I type a value from given values, it still identifies it as invalid:
[image]

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57981906/google-sheets-data-validation-dropdown-from-single-cell-csv) it says that it is actually not possible, but otherwise, my data column will grow very big, that's why I wanted to keep it in a single cell.

Method to reproduce: Just make a copy of [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m_SVdfnY4ytf1-8InKJWldJDj5AOmPOoM7CbssqV9Rg/edit?usp=sharing) and experiment on your own whatever you want it to be like:

Comment: I think this is not possible. You can google it, there are many references to this issue. Your only option is to create a list of items and then reference to the range of this list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do this from the sheets editor, but you could use [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) to accomplish this:

- Open the script editor by selecting **Tools > Script editor**.
- Copy and run this function:

```
function createDataValidation() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const values = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue().split(","); // Get array with values from A1
  const rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(values); // Create DV
  sheet.getRange("F8").setDataValidation(rule); // Set DV to F8
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Class DataValidationBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder)